# Form Submission in Pop Up Window using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement that i have to submit a form with values in javascript.
 That method is "POST" type.

The form submission should be in new pop up window.
 The current window will have to remains the same.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<form action="..." method="post" onsubmit="target_popup(this)">

</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function target_popup(form) {
    window.open('', 'formpopup', 'width=400,height=400,resizeable,scrollbars');
    form.target = 'formpopup';
}
```

Comment: I had tried it But it is not working.I am submiting the Form in Javascript as "document.forms["myForm"].submit();" Now i have to submit this form and this should be open in pop up.